# O notation: 2^log(O(n^2)) = 2^O(log(n^2))?

Tags: math, big-o, time-complexity

I tried to solve this with logarithm rules:

O(n^2) = 2^O(log(n^2))

c*n^2 = 2^log(n^2c)

Im not sure that is true?

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on what the equals sign means here. If the equals sign means

"Any function that is of 2<sup>log O(n<sup>2</sup>)</sup> is also 2<sup>O(log n<sup>2</sup>)</sup>"

Then the claim is true. Let f(n) be some function that's O(n<sup>2</sup>). This means that there's a c and n<sub>0</sub> such that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, we know that f(n) ≤ cn<sup>2</sup>. Therefore, for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, we know that

> 2<sup>log f(n)</sup> ≤ 2<sup>log (cn<sup>2</sup>)</sup> = 2<sup>(log c + log n<sup>2</sup>)</sup>

The function log c + log n<sup>2</sup> is itself O(log n<sup>2</sup>), so we see that

> 2<sup>log f(n)</sup> ≤ 2<sup>(log c + log n<sup>2</sup>)</sup> = 2<sup>O(log n<sup>2</sup>)</sup>

On the other hand, if the equals sign means

"The class of functions that is 2<sup>log O(n<sup>2</sup>)</sup> is the same class of functions that is 2<sup>O(log n<sup>2</sup>)</sup>"

then the claim is false. For example, the function n<sup>4</sup> is in the second class because it can be written as 2<sup>2 log n<sup>2</sup></sup>, but it's not in the first class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no. You can't just take logarithms.

2^log (O (n^2)) = 2 ^ log (c * n^2)) = c * n^2

2^ O (log n^2) = 2^ (c * log n^2) = (2 ^ (log n^2)) ^ c = (n^2) ^ c.

The first is just O (n^2). The second one is n raised to sum unknown but limited power.